# Correr aplicacion de Flutter en dispotivo fisico

Tags: android, flutter, vscode

Acabo de conectar mi celular en la pc para trabajar con Flutter en vscode pero cuando intento usar la paleta de comandos en Flutter:select device no me aparece mi celular, esta es la configuracion de mi celular. que estoy haciendo mal?

[image]

Comment: ejecuta el comando `flutter devices` y muestranos que sale

Comment: me aparece esto:
No devices detected.

Run 'flutter emulators' to list and start any available device emulators.

Or, if you expected your device to be detected, please run "flutter doctor" to diagnose potential issues, or visit
https://flutter.dev/setup/ for troubleshooting tips.

Comment: Al parecer no reconoce tu dispositivo, si estas en windows tienes que instalar los drivers me parece. revisa esto : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb

Comment: me dicen que son los drivers pero el dispositivo me aparece en el equipo y puedo acceder a las targetas de memoria del celular, o eso no tiene nada que ver?

Comment: si el comando flutter devices no lo reconoce, entonces no, quizas en tu dispositivo puedes cambiar la forma en que se conecta, no recuredo bien las opciones que te aparece, una es transferencia de datos y hay más ..

Comment: perdon por no contestar pero la solucion era instalar ADB interface